# How to get adobe air air.navigateToURL(urlReq) to bring default browser to focus

Tags: air, adobe

I'm working with adobe air and I have this code..

```
var urlReq = new air.URLRequest('http://google.com'); 
air.navigateToURL(urlReq);
```

It's working correctly in that it is loading the page in the browser, but the issue is that adobe air is staying in the front and the browser is not being brought to the front...

Perhaps it's because I'm working in runtime and not a complied app?

(just off to try that now)

Comment: I'm struggling with this too...does anyone have a solution? I have FF 3.6 as my default browser.

Answer (score 1):

```
air.navigateToURL(urlReq, "_blank");
```

does that do the trick? It works with my compiled apps...

Answer (score 0):

Does this happen when your default browser is IE? What if your default browser is Firefox?

Answer (score 0):

In a desktop air app, this do the job:

```
var url:String = "http://google.com";
navigateToURL( new URLRequest(url) );
```

Never try in a compiled air app. [StageWebView](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/media/StageWebView.html) can help you, or you can try with 'url schemes'. I know there is one for googlechrome:

```
navigateToURL( new URLRequest( "googlechrome://google.com") );
```